# Which vendors/companies have Multi-threaded Video codec solutions?

Tags: multithreading, video, encoding, decoding, codec

If its not relevant here, pls. move to correct place.

I want to find out which all vendors/companies have developed multi-threaded video codecs(decoders , encoders) as commercial products? Not opensource solutions like libavcodec/x264/ffdshow etc... but commercial solutions for which one can obtain licenses/performance numbers of those solutions.

thanks,

-AD.

Comment: Paying for the implementation does NOT mean that you have a license. http://bemasc.net/wordpress/2010/02/02/no-you-cant-do-that-with-h264/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainConcept has some excellent codec options.  They offer support for multi-threading as well as support for hardware accelerated encoding:

[MainConcept Codec SDK](http://www.mainconcept.com/site/developer-products-6/pc-based-sdks-20974/codec-sdk-20946/information-20962.html?L=0)

In my opinion they offer the best performance and quality (no I do not work for MainConcept).